# Android Variable Application

Tags: java, android, variables

Here is my some part of my code.

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  
    setContentView(R.layout.main);  
    IntentFilter intent = new IntentFilter();
    intent.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_ACL_CONNECTED);

    registerReceiver(searchDevices, intent);  

    private BroadcastReceiver searchDevices = new BroadcastReceiver() {  
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String a="1";
        }
    }


    class ClickEvent implements View.OnClickListener {  
        public void onClick(View v) {
           // here , how to get Variables in a , I can't direct use of a
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: he has written the question in code in comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare as `final String a="1";`

Comment: even if he does, I dont think it will be visible to onclick listener. Should be global i think.

Answer (score 0):

`String a="1"`;
 change

```
public final String a="1";
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a class member, then all inner classes ie the listeners can access it.

in the top level define

```
    private String a;
```

and then in the other classes just use like any other member variable i.e

```
    a="1";
```